# Confirmation message on user input in php

Tags: php, javascript

I have a doubt in the following code. I have a single function for both Insert and Update. Based on the row count each function will be executed. I want to provide a Confirmation box before performing the operation. On cancel message it should not perform the function. How can I do this?
Following is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['Save']))

{

$query = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `submission_id` = '$submission_id'";

$sqlsearch = mysql_query($query);

$resultcount = mysql_num_rows($sqlsearch);


if ($resultcount > 0) 
{
mysql_query("UPDATE `table_name` SET 
    `name` = '$name',
    `email` = '$email',
    `phone` = '$phonenumber',
    `subject` = '$subject',
    `message` = '$message' 
    WHERE `submission_id` = '$submission_id'") or die(mysql_error());
} 
else 
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table_name` (submission_id, formID, IP, 
    name, email, phone, subject, message) 
    VALUES ('$submission_id', '$formID', '$ip', 
    '$name', '$email', '$phonenumber', '$subject', '$message') ") or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
?>`
```

Comment: Use JS, show dialog box when form is submitted. If yes, submit the form else ignore.

Comment: The problem is, i have two functions(insert and update) to be performed in a single function called save.

Comment: You question is NOT self explanatory.

Comment: My code clearly explains what i have done. My question is , i want to add a msg box on update. When clicked yes it must perform update else it must not perform update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try javascript `confirm` function on `onsubmit` form action

```
var conf=confirm('Are You Sure You Want to Add/Edit?');
if(conf){
 return true; //perform the task
}else{
  return false; // Cancel the task
}
```

**Updated**:

Have a hidden value in form, call the js action if id is set, something like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id;?>" />
```

then,

```
var user_id= $('#user_id').val();
if(user_id) {
  var conf=confirm('Are You Sure You Want to Update?');
    if(conf){
     return true; //perform the task
    }else{
      return false; // Cancel the task
    }
}else{
//your action
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have one more doubt, When they update user must be prompted a msg " Do you want to update?" If yes update query must be executed if they click no update query must not be performed. I dont know how to implement this using the js and pass the variables to php. pls help

Comment: i need to insert the update query in the first part if condition that performs the task???

Comment: If i click cancel in the msg box, my update query is performed. It should not. How can i do this

Comment: Thanks alot for your help :) @LearneR ... Your code worked out for me :) :) but i m not getting the msg , it says undefined

Comment: I found out @LearneR :) Thanks alot :) Your code helped me finally ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$resultcount = mysql_numrows($sqlsearch);
```

To this:

```
$resultcount = mysql_num_rows($sqlsearch);
```

Answer (score 0):

make the confirmation box showing onClick event for your 'save button':

```
<input type="submit" name="save" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you to....?')">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add validation to the onsubmit attribute on your form. (The form will not submit when clicked no)

```
<form name="example" action="saver.php" onsubmit="return confirm('Confirmation Message');">
<!-- Inputs / Elements -->
</form>
```

Regarding your other query (Passing your Javascript result to your PHP file):

If you want the value of what the user has choosen you could insert a hidden field with the status of the confirmation box. E.g.

```
<form name="example" action="saver.php" onsubmit="return updateExecuted();">
<input type="hidden" id="confirmationStatus" name="confirmationStatus" />
<!-- Inputs / Elements -->
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateExecuted(){
       var con=confirm('Confirmation question');
       if(con){
          document.getElementById('confirmationStatus').value = "yes";
       }
       else{
          document.getElementById('confirmationStatus').value = "no";
          //See comments below regarding - return false;
       }
       return true;
    }
</script>
```

This is an example of how to pass the javascript confirmation result variable into the php file. You can check the state of this variable in the php file by referencing `$_POST['confirmationStatus']` value.

Im in a bit of a rush but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you PhilNerd. I try this one :)

Comment: If i click cancel in the msg box, my update query is performed. It should not. How can i do this

Comment: Add return false below in the else section. 

This is an example of how to pass the variable to the php file. you could also add a if statement in the php file to check the $_POST['confirmation'] value.

Comment: I thought this was answer was accepted, was it by mistake? @user1711717

Answer (score 0):

just add this in your form

```
onsubmit="return confirm('Your Confirmation Message');">
```

in your case

```
<input type="submit" name="save" onsubmit="return confirm('Your Confirmation Message');>
```